# Overly broad permission ask for google youtube API

Tags: google-api, youtube

I'm using the YouTube API to create a webpage that allows users to view a specific set of YouTube videos, and then LIKE those videos, using YouTube like/dislike rating system, and It's working fine, but when the user triggers the process, after logging into their google account, they are presented with a permission dialog that basically says

> "Hey, this site wants complete and total control over your YouTube account!".

[image]

I DO NOT want that, I only want the user to be able to rate the videos.
I'm using the PHP Client library to pull the list of videos into the page and display them, and this requires no permissions or interaction from the user. I am also using the JS library to handle the "like" functionality, and it's basically the javascript example from https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/rate?apix=true, but with my credentials.

Can I change this somewhere, or does YouTube just lump all of it's permissions under one giant "I can do anything" permission group?

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code questions with out an example arent useful. and its hard to help you fix your issue without seeing the code itself.

Comment: I thought it just let you control upload and configuration of videos on the users account.   Does the YouTube api even allow you to post likes and dislikes on behalf of a user?   That will be nice if they enabled that

Comment: Yes, they do allow you to post likes and dislikes on behalf of the user, but the user has to login through the oauth panel first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It's about the OAuth 2 scopes, which the example lets you change for the DEMO, but it doesn't actually change the code in the sample.

For reference, the list of scopes is here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes#youtubev3